# CAGradientLayer not filling width

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am relatively new to Swift. I'm just messing around trying to design a taxi app.

I discovered `CGGradientLayer` and thought it would add a nice effect to the top bar on the app.

I've added it and for some reason, it's not fully stretching to the views width.

This is my subclass:

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupGradientView()
    }

    func setupGradientView() {
        gradient.frame = self.frame
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.init(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.locations = [0.9, 1.0]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

And this is the result.

The green background is actually the width of the `UIView` which the sub class is applied too.

[image]

Comment: `gradient.frame` should be `self.bounds`, just in case. But for the rest, I'd say that you are drawing the Gradient to soon. In Interface Builder, your View has a size, but it size change to adapt to the constraint/device, which isn't taking in account. A way do do it would be to wait for the `layoutDidSubView()`, or maybe by overriding `setFrame:` and change the the bounds of your gradient there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting the `frame` of the gradient too early.  You should set it up in an `override` of `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Notes:

- You should be setting the gradient frame to `self.bounds`.  That is the coordinate system used inside of the view.  The gradient is placed relative to the `GradientView` and doesn't change if the `GradientView` is placed in another location on the screen (because the `bounds` do not change in that case, but the `frame` does).
- At the time your view is first created, *Auto Layout* has not established the size of your view for your current device (or orientation).  By setting the `frame` in `layoutSubviews` you always get the latest value for the size of the view.